# Howto reflect object into an only at runtime known type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, casting

i have a little big problem.
My problem is the following.

I´ve got two types: AssetData and AssetData. They are basicly the same, but not inherited.
Now i have i know a property with the Type "AssetData", and i have a object of type AssetData (containing a Texture2D object).

Now i want to cast the AssetData object into the AssetData object. Because i don´t know the generic parameter, AssetData has now operator for that kind of cast, but AssetData is able to cast to AssetData.

I tried and tried what i could do to solve it, but i have no more ideas.

Here´s my situation: I´ve got a type of a property, i have a AssetData with the same object, but i must set the AssetData to the property - so i have to set "AssetData", not AssetData.

Here´s my code. I can´t hardcode it, because it would be to much to change after adding new types. That´s my latest try. It nearly works, but has the problem that the cast does not work, because there´s no operator of AssetData ...

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pinf in comp.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cdata.PInf.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (cdata.PInf[i] != pinf.Name) continue;

                    AssetData assetData = new AssetData
                                              {
                                                  AssetName = cdata.AN[i],
                                                  AssetType = Type.GetType(cdata.AT[i], true)
                                              };
                    Application.Game.GetSystem<ContentManager>().LoadContent(ref assetData);

                    if (pinf.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
                    {
                        MethodInfo method = typeof (DynamicCast).GetMethod("Cast").GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(
                                assetData.AssetType);

                        Type castedAssetType =
                            pinf.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(assetData.AssetType);

                        dynamic castedAsset = method.Invoke(typeof (DynamicCast), new[] {assetData});

                        pinf.SetValue(comp, castedAsset, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And here´s the method of "DynamicCast" - which i found on an blog. This also doesn´t work ...

```
    public static class DynamicCast
{
    public static T Cast<T>(object o)
    {
        Type ot = o.GetType();
        MethodInfo meth = GetMethod(ot, "op_Implicit", typeof(T),
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (meth == null)
        {
            meth = GetMethod(ot, "op_Explicit", typeof(T),
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        }

        if (meth == null) throw new InvalidCastException("Invalid Cast.");

        return (T) meth.Invoke(null, new[] {o});
    }

    public static MethodInfo GetMethod(Type toSearch, string methodName,
        Type returnType, BindingFlags bindingFlags)
    {
        return Array.Find(
            toSearch.GetMethods(bindingFlags),
            inf => ((inf.Name == methodName) && (inf.ReturnType == returnType)));
    }
}
```

The problem is, that i must create an AssetData object (in this case), and set it as value for the property. But the object is clear, so i must cast AssetData´s "Asset"-property to the "AssetData"´s. Both are the same type, but one is "object" and one "T" (Texture2D).

How can i cast this?

Thanks a lot! I´m workin on this since the midday ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution...

I just had to add an generic method "Cast()" to AssetData. I just came on this idea, because now i know i can invoke a generic method ;)

Here´s the solution:

```
if (pinf.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
{
    MethodInfo method =
        assetData.GetType().GetMethod("Cast").GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(
            assetData.AssetType);

    dynamic castedAsset = method.Invoke(assetData, null);

    pinf.SetValue(comp, castedAsset, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `dynamic`.

```
public static class DynamicCast
{
    public static T Cast<T>(object o)
    {
        return (T) (dynamic) o;
    }
}
```

This will automatically use any implicit/explicit operators that exist on the run-time type of `o` and/or the type `T`. (Your code is incomplete because you’re searching only one of the two.)

The rest of your question is extremely unclear. You need to rephrase it. The code is also unclear: what is the variable `castedAssetType` for? You are only assigning to it but then not using it.

Comment: Ehm, it doesn´t work. But please wait for some minutes. I´m trying something different...

Comment: Could have been nice to mention that this requires C# 4.0 and the DLR

Comment: @sehe: Should I also mention that this requires a compiler? And that it requires a computer? Come on.

Comment: Well, not everyone has it, clearly the OP wasn't previously aware of it, _AND_ you brisked _him_ of for being extremely unclear? I think it is fair to be a bit more forthcoming, or less demanding on the other hand. Gave you a +1 by the way, because it is obviously a good answer :)